Executing JavaScript on page load in Symfony 7 using AssetMapper fails after following a link
I'm trying to implement BootStrap's color switcher in Symfony.
I've added BootStrap using AssetMapper and everything is working.
I've then copied the color switcher from BootStrap's examples page into a twig template along with it's CSS and JS code (as assets).
I have a Controller routed to / whose template includes the color switcher template.
Everything appears to work when I open the page in the browser, however if I add a link in that page - to itself or to a different page, doesn't matter - the color switcher won't work in the new page, unless I press F5 or reload the page in some other fashion.
I've discovered that the JavaScript code that initializes the color switcher is run on the initial page load or when I reload, but when changing pages by clicking a link it does not execute again on the destination page.
I've tried adding something like:
if (document.readyState !== 'loading') {
    console.log('document is already ready, just execute code here');
    initThemeSwitcher();
} else {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        console.log('document was not ready, place code here');
        initThemeSwitcher();
    });
}

and whatching the console, again, only on initial page load or a forced reload will this code run.
So my question is: Why will this code only run when the file is fetched from the server and not on moving to a different page (or same page) by clicking a link?
EDIT Just noticed the same thing happens with Stimulus Controllers: They work on page load but the moment I follow a link, they stop working until I reload the page (F5 on keyboard for example)

Hello, I'm encountering the same issue. Did you find a solution without having to use a Stimulus Controller?

No - what is in my answer is the one solution that worked for me - maybe you could remove @hotwired/turbo and @hotwired/stimulus if you're really not going to take advantage of them, but I haven't tried that and can't say if there will be any other consequences from removing them

To be clear - I believe @hotwired/turbo specifiacally is responsable for this behaviour of code set to run on DOMLoaded only running on first page load - unless the page has a different entrypoint from importmap

I'm still not sure why adding an EventListener to DOMContentLoaded only works on the first page loaded, but I managed to get a workaround.
Instead of using the code "as is" from the bootstrap site, I made a Stimulus Controller out of it - with a few changes to the code so it wouldn't use DOMContentLoaded.
I ended up with the following Stimulus Controller:
import { Controller } from '@hotwired/stimulus';

export default class extends Controller {
    'use strict'
    connect() {        
        const preferredTheme = this.getPreferredTheme()
        this.setTheme(preferredTheme)
        this.showActiveTheme(preferredTheme, false)

        window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').addEventListener('change', () => {
            const storedTheme = this.getStoredTheme()
            if (storedTheme !== 'light' && storedTheme !== 'dark') {
                this.setTheme(this.getPreferredTheme())
            }
        })
        
        document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-theme-value]').forEach(toggle => {
            toggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
                const theme = toggle.getAttribute('data-bs-theme-value')
                this.setStoredTheme(theme)
                this.setTheme(theme)
                this.showActiveTheme(theme, true)
            })
        })
    }
    
    getStoredTheme() {
        return localStorage.getItem('theme')
    }
    
    setStoredTheme(theme) {
        localStorage.setItem('theme', theme)
    }

    getPreferredTheme() {
        const storedTheme = this.getStoredTheme()
        if (storedTheme) {
            return storedTheme
        }

        return window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches ? 'dark' : 'light'
    }

    setTheme(theme) {
        if (theme === 'auto') {
            document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-bs-theme', (window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches ? 'dark' : 'light'))
        } else {
            document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-bs-theme', theme)
        }
    }

    showActiveTheme(theme, focus = false) {
        const themeSwitcher = document.querySelector('#bd-theme')

        if (!themeSwitcher) {
            return
        }

        const themeSwitcherText = document.querySelector('#bd-theme-text')
        const activeThemeIcon = document.querySelector('.theme-icon-active use')
        const btnToActive = document.querySelector(`[data-bs-theme-value="${theme}"]`)
        const svgOfActiveBtn = btnToActive.querySelector('svg use').getAttribute('href')

        document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-theme-value]').forEach(element => {
            element.classList.remove('active')
            element.setAttribute('aria-pressed', 'false')
        })

        btnToActive.classList.add('active')
        btnToActive.setAttribute('aria-pressed', 'true')
        activeThemeIcon.setAttribute('href', svgOfActiveBtn)
        const themeSwitcherLabel = `${themeSwitcherText.textContent} (${btnToActive.dataset.bsThemeValue})`
        themeSwitcher.setAttribute('aria-label', themeSwitcherLabel)

        if (focus) {
            themeSwitcher.focus()
        }
    }
}


When installing turbo your solution (using stimulus) is the actual solution symfony docs suggest:
Because navigation no longer results in full page refreshes, you may need to adjust your JavaScript to work properly. The best solution is to write your JavaScript using Stimulus or something similar.
ref: https://symfony.com/bundles/ux-turbo/current/index.html#usage

@pok_net isn't what you're saying exactly what my answer does?

yes that is correct. I just wanted to make clear that this behaviour is by design and that your solution is suggested by symfony docs as the prefered best practice.

I have found a solution to my problem based on the comments from 537mfb.

No - what is in my answer is the one solution that worked for me - maybe you could remove @hotwired/turbo and @hotwired/stimulus if you're really not going to take advantage of them, but I haven't tried that and can't say if there will be any other consequences from removing them


To be clear - I believe @hotwired/turbo specifiacally is responsable for this behaviour of code set to run on DOMLoaded only running on first page load - unless the page has a different entrypoint from importmap

Here's what I did to resolve the issue:

I removed symfony/ux-turbo from my project:
composer remove stimulus-bundle


I also removed the following references for AssetMapper:
php bin/console importmap:remove @hotwired/stimulus
php bin/console importmap:remove @hotwired/turbo
php bin/console importmap:remove @symfony/stimulus-bundle


In my app.js file, I removed this import:
import './bootstrap.js';



After making these changes, my JS files load correctly with each navigation, and I no longer experience the issue.
I am not sure about potential side effects, as I haven't dug deeper into this and my project isn't very large.
Thanks to 537mfb for the helpful information!
